# error MSB6006: "svnversion.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: c#, svn, msbuildcommunitytasks, assemblyinfo

I am trying to get revision number from svn to put on my AssemblyInfo.cs file. I already made that on my computer and works fine. But when I use hudson to build and deploy my application automatically on server then this error appears. Anyone knows why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are using a old version of svnversion.

Try to open the Command Line Prompt, navigate to the svnversion directory and do the same job as the MSBuild.

CMD:

```
cd C:\ProgramFiles\TortoiseSVN\bin
[ENTER]
svnversion C:\VisualStudio\Projects\YourDirectory
[ENTER]

SVNVERSION should answer why its not working, in my case was by E155021: This client is too old to work with thew working copy at...
```

Comment: In my case the SlikSVN was never, a rollback to a previous version fixed everything.